# Index and import HTML not working in Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract the certain value of a Single row of html table in 5th Row and third column from the below mentioned link

https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=2020-02-07

the formula that I have used as mentioned below:

=index(IMPORTHTML("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=USD&date=2020-02-07","table",0),5,3)

The formula doesnt extract the value in the cell instead it displays in the popup of google sheets.

I am looking to extract single value in **5th Row and third column** . I tried using index and importxml but could not get any value.

Please help with the requiste formula to get the desired result .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula seems to work fine for me.

[image: Example]